# nothing fires after fetch data from DB react native

Tags: react-native, fetch, rerender

i have `index.js` contain's `Tabs` each tab render the same component (`animate.js`)  but with different props, the code as the following:

**index.js**

```
categoryList.map((item,index) => {
    if(item.head_category == category_id)
      return (
          <Tab heading={item.category_name} key={index}>
            <Animate category_id={item.category_id}/>
          </Tab>
        )
    });
```

in the `animate.js` i receive the `category_id` number and fetch the data using redux , and the data gets back

for first `animate.js` rendering nothing fires after the data returns but if i switch the tabs everything works grate

**animate.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { InteractionManager, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {LineDotsLoader} from 'react-native-indicator';

import {goodsAction} from './redux/actions'

class animate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      category_id:'',
      loading:true,
    };
    console.log('constructor');
  }
componentDidMount(){
  const { category_id, category_name } = this.props;
  this.props.goodsAction({category_id}); // My fetching Action
  console.log(`componentDidMount `);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(`componentWillReceiveProps`)
}
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
  console.log(` getDerivedStateFromProps `);
  return null;
  }
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(` componentDidUpdate `);
  }

  renderPage() {    
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        // anything 
      </View>
    );
  }
  render(props) {
    console.log(`render`);
if (this.props.loading) { 
// if redux still fetching return loading:true else return false
  return(<View style={styles.container}><LineDotsLoader /></View>)}
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.renderPage()} // or anything
        </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    error: state.goods.error,
    loading: state.goods.loading,
    goods: state.goods.goods
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { goodsAction })(animate);
```

my console image

[image: console log]

**Edit**

and this is my `goodsRedusers.js`

```
import {
  GOODS_LOADING_ATTEMPT,
  GOODS_REFRESH_ATTEMPT,
  GOODS_LOADED,
  GOODS_FAILED
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { goods:[], loading: true, error: '', }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GOODS_LOADING_ATTEMPT://dispatch before connecting to db
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, loading: true }
    case GOODS_FAILED:
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, loading: false, error: action.error  }
    case GOODS_LOADED://dispatch after data gets back
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, loading: false, goods: action.goods  }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you making sure you return new objects from the reducer instead of modifying the old one? Can you share your reducer?

Comment: i update the question @ViniciusCleves

Answer (score 0):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
  console.log(` getDerivedStateFromProps `);
  return null;
  }
```

Returning `null` won't update the state when props change, if that's what you want.
Try removing this code.

Comment: it's the same, nothing changed @Nishant Nair

Comment: Is the action `goodsAction` dispatching correctly? Check if the props are updating in the `animate.js` component

Comment: the `goodsAction` dispatching correctly 
and as i mention before

: 
for first `animate.js` rendering, nothing fires after the data returns but if i switch the tabs everything works grate